# Java Web Start and Windows Admin Rights Affecting client-server communication

Tags: java, windows, security, java-web-start

**Update**: I no longer need this, we have a different solution for clients who have this problem.
Thanks to everyone who tried to answer..

I tried JWS FAQ, Google, stackoverflow and found nothing helpful..

**The question is**: What is the effect of a Windows 7 machine with minimum rights on java web start application communicating with a webserver

**The scenarios at hand**:

- I have a Java web start application that sends requests and gets responses from a server. The server address is https://.......
- When I run it on a Windows 7 machine that has admin rights, everything works well.
- When running the same JWS app on a laptop running Windows 7 with minimum rights, and with restrictions managed by some company's IT service (I'm still trying to understand and find out what these restrictions are exactly), I can run the application, but I don't have communication with my server. Meaning, I can't even pass login in my JWS app. In the server logs, I didn't see any logs about incoming requests from my app.
- When I try to communicate with a similar server, with http address (not https), I see in the server logs that traffic is coming in and out, but the JWS app fails to receive responses to the requests it sends to the server.
- When trying to run the same application but as regular java app (not JWS), it works just fine with either https server and http server.

Update: I read here - http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/deployment/webstart/security.html

that adding

`<security>
   <all-permissions/>
</security>`

is supposed to help, but I checked and it already was there to begin with, so that is not the way..

Edit - Tried @AndrewThompson's JaNeLA and got:

```
Content type application/x-java-jnlp-file;charset=ISO-8859-1 does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

**Update (Sept. 15th 2014)**: I no longer need this, we have a different solution for clients who have this problem.
Thanks to everyone who tried to answer..

Comment: I don't know that this is the answer to your question, but Windows has a firewall that restricts which applications can communicate over the Internet.  Unless your application is on a white list for the particular Windows computer, it cannot communicate over the Internet.  Even when running as an administrator, a option box will pop up asking if you'll allow process x to communicate over the Internet.

Comment: I would also suggest you got to the Windows Control Panel -> Java and turn go the Advanced tab.  There you can enable tracing, enable debugging and also enable the Java console.  Between these 3 options, hopefully you will get a hint as to what's going on.  Also, what version of Java are you running?  Because there are new security changes starting in J7 Update51 and beyond for applets and JWS clients.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replays. The said laptop is not in my possession, so it'll take some time to check all that you suggest. And to be more specific...

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - thanls, I'm still in the process of getting in touch with the IT who controls that laptop, to better understand the restrictions.

Comment: @mikemil - I was using Java 7, not sure which update, but will check it. Thanks for the suggestions..

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I gave JaNeLA a try, but got this weird error.. Weird because the charset is not set in the jsp file creating the jnlp..

Content type application/x-java-jnlp-file;charset=ISO-8859-1 does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: Are those two **separate lines** of output?  Post the entire output as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22689040/edit).  Use code formatting.

Comment: Yes, theses are two separated lines. I edited the question at its end